# python matplotlib axes3d lines cross neglecting depth

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting several lines in 3D the last line allways covers previeously plotted lines even if it is behind it.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    def sinus(t,a,n):
            y = [1.0*a*np.sin(2.0*np.pi*t*n+0),1.0*a*np.sin(2.0*np.pi*t*n+2.0*np.pi/3),1.0*a*np.sin(2.0*np.pi*t*n+4.0*np.pi/3)]
            z = [1.0*a*np.cos(2.0*np.pi*t*n+0),1.0*a*np.cos(2.0*np.pi*t*n+2.0*np.pi/3),1.0*a*np.cos(2.0*np.pi*t*n+4.0*np.pi/3)]
            return y,z

    t = np.linspace(0,1,1e6)
    Y,Z = sinus(t,2,2)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    for i in range(0,len(Y)):
            print(i,len(Y))
            ax.plot(t, Y[i],zs=Z[i],linewidth=4.0)
    plt.show()
```

In the [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybKBq.png) the red line allways covers the blue or green line even though it should pass behind it. The expected behaviour would be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNRaY.png). How can this be achieved with python?

Comment: For me the lines cover each other in order of appearance. You're relying on the default colors because you don't specify them in your plot; perhaps you're misunderstanding the color order. Try something like `for i,clr in zip(range(0,len(Y)),('red','blue','green')):` and `ax.plot(t, Y[i],zs=Z[i],linewidth=4.0, color=clr)` to confirm that your colors are what you think they are.

Comment: correct, but the colors are not the problem. The problem is that the red line always covers the others, even in the cases where it is further away from the viewpoint than the other lines. A different example would be one helix circling around a line. Even though the line is inside of the helix, You could only generate a plot where it is either behind (first plot the line and then the helix) or in front of (first plot the helix and then the line)

Comment: Correct. Each line is a single object. It is either drawn above or below some other line or element in the plot. This is also discussed in [the matplotlib 3D FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles). You may still try to divide your lines into individual sections such that they can appear above or below other sections of other lines.

Comment: oh dear... thanks for point that out, I should have found that myself. I'll have a look into MayaVi.